# Calling System.IO.ReadAllBytes by string name

Tags: vb.net, reflection

**This post is related to Visual Basic .NET 2010**

So, I'm wondering if there's any way to call a function from a library such as `System.ReadAllBytes` by string name.

I've been trying `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance` and `System.Activator.CreateInstance` followed by `CallByName()`, but none of them seemed to work.

Example of how I tried it:

```
Dim Inst As Object = Activator.CreateInstance("System.IO", False, New Object() {})
Dim Obj As Byte() = DirectCast(CallByName(Inst, "ReadAllBytes", CallType.Method, new object() {"C:\file.exe"}), Byte())
```

Help is (as always) much appreciated

Comment: Well thats Odd. You mean to create an instance of `System.IO`? Thats a namespace... surely you mean to create an instance of `System.IO.FileStream` (with the filename as parameter) and then call `ReadAllBytes` ... but why do you bother with Reflection at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()`, you missed the "File" part.  Which is a *Shared* method, the CallByName statement is not flexible enough to permit calling such methods.  You will need to use the more universal Reflection that's available in .NET.  Which looks like this for your specific example, spelled out for clarity:

```
Imports System.Reflection

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim type = GetType(System.IO.File)
        Dim method = type.GetMethod("ReadAllBytes")
        Dim result = method.Invoke(Nothing, New Object() {"c:\temp\test.bin"})
        Dim bytes = DirectCast(result, Byte())
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: I used System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes() as an example, if the class needs to be instanced, would I still use the same method?

Comment: Yes.  Pass the class object instead of *Nothing* in the Invoke() call.

Comment: But if the System.IO.File needs to be in a string as well, is that even possible or am I just daydreaming here?

Comment: It's possible, Assembly.GetType().  Which now passes the buck to getting the Assembly object, Assembly.Load().  You do ultimately have to have some idea where the type lives.

Comment: I've tried your code, but for some reason I end up with an error when using it like so: http://pastebin.com/rwusCsHA

Comment: Sure, "type" is not the correct object in the Invoke() method.  You need an instance of the ResourceManager class, not an instance of the Type class.  You can get one from My.Resources.ResourceManager, perhaps.  This is a good example of when *not* to use Reflection, ResourceManager.GetObject() already takes a string argument.